Problem with PageController in Flutter: "ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views"
I've implemented a PageView in my Flutter app. When I leave the page by logging out and come back after logging in, I get the following error message:
ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 158 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1'

The PageView is stored in a Riverpod provider, which is invalidated when the page is left. However, the error still occurs. Here is my code:
The Logout Method:
menuButton(
                onTap: () {
                  LoginController().logout();
                  ref.invalidate(homePageProvider);
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginNew.routeName);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
                title: AppLocalizationUtil.of(context)!.log_out
            ),

The Provider:
final homePageProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose((ref) => HomePageState());

class HomePageState extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  PageController _pageController = PageController();

  int get selectedIndex => _selectedIndex;

  get pageController => _pageController;


  void changeVisibility(int index) {
    pageController.animateToPage(index,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    _selectedIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

The Page view is stored directly within the body tag of a Scaffold
How can I avoid this error and use the PageController properly?

These values belong in local widget state, see ephemeral vs app state. Also, Riverpod suggests to avoid using providers for local widget state.

What about using Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, LoginNew.routeName); instead? Because you're currently keeping the HomePage in the pages' stack (with pushNamed), which wouldn't occur with pushReplacementNamed, and so I guess you currently instanciate HomePage a second time in the LoginNew when you push it up on login success.
